# Refactoring MVC controller code. Controller or model

Tags: model-view-controller

I have a lot of code in a controller and I'm not sure where to put it. First I re-factored it so that it is DRY but still in the controller.

What is a good guideline to follow when re-factoring code, such as when to move something to a model and when to keep something in a controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your model generally should contain no business logic. If it does, extract that model out into a `ViewModel` and the only logic in it should be your display related code. Any business methods should exist in a separate class. Some prefer to use `ViewModels` all the time instead of general overall models (ex. `CustomerEditViewModel` instead of just a `Customer model`).

The controller should be very lightweight and should not have data access code in it. I generally call a repository method ([Repository Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html)) to easily load data and the [Facade Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) as a gateway to any business methods that are performed.

For instance, rather than having data loading code, some calculations, and some saving code, this could all be put into a facade class that takes a model or `customerId` and does something like:

```
CustomerRepository repository = new CustomerRepository();
Customer customer = repository.GetCustomer(customerId);
// call some business methods, assign data, etc.
..
..
// now save
repository.SaveCustomer(customer);
```

Your repository class is usually coded to an interface; this makes stubbing out/mocking these classes to load 'fake' data extremely easy and also decouples your controller and facade from linking directly to a concrete implementation of a class, but instead to an interface.

Answer (score 2):

The controller should primarily contain coordination code.  So if, by some chance, you have code performing some business or domain function you could move *that*.  I tend to use application services or simple tasks.  Something like IImageService or IDocumentService (although the implementations can become quite bloated).  I also like using individual tasks such as ILoginTask.

The implementations are then injected (I use Castle Windsor with a custom controller factory).

Just my 2c --- HTH